# React - Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help me out.
I am beginner at React. However, i am still learning day by day.

So i want to implement the dropdown just like below. It is from one of the E-Commerce website.

E-Commerce Dropdown Image:

[image]

I am trying to implement it through Bootstrap but the dropdown doesn't seem to work at all.

Any help would be appreciated. Just guide me to the relevant tutorial. I have watched many videos on YT but couldn't find anyone related to mine one.

PS: Sorry, I dont know how to show the image directly here. It is my first time asking question here.

Comment: you need to show us some code

Comment: Bro, for testing purposes, i copied the whole dropdown code from bootstrap and used it in react. Changed relevant names according to React like className etc.

Answer (score 2):

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ is an excellent library that I’ve used in the past. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any code, I assume you are not loading Bootstrap's assets.

To load them, go to your App.js, and at the top write:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```